# Error while using property 'CGRectGetWidth', it says it was replaced with 'CGRect.width'

Tags: swift, cgrect

When I'm using this code, I get an error:

```
let d = translation.x / CGRectGetWidth(pan.view!.bounds) * 0.5
```

> 'CGRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.width'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You should get the width directly from the `bounds` property.

```
let d = translation.x / pan.view!.bounds.width * 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGRectGetWidth` has been removed in swift 3 and now you can get width directly

```
let d = translation.x / (pan.view!.bounds.width) * 0.5
```

hope its works..

Comment: There is no difference from the4kman's answer and the parentheses are pointless.